# Wordpress AJAX request returning extra HTML tags

Tags: ajax, wordpress, internet-explorer

I am using Knews plugin for subscribing to my website. Everything is working except IE8: in IE 8 error or success message is not showing. I think since this is an AJAXed form I am getting an AJAX response with some unnecessary HTML tags.

Please see the screenshot. I provide this in the backend:

```
<span class="error_subscription">Please check e-mail Address</span>
```

But I am getting the response as on the screenshot:

```
<span class="error_subscription">Please check e-mail Address</span></p></div>
```

[image: ajax request]

Comment: This might be caused by the 'body' and 'html, body' call difference in IE browsers in javascript call. Or z-index is wrong. Can you check if the html you receive is embedded to the page (from elements tab)